# How can I track a file?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I have a XML file saved on my desktop. Is there any possible way to track the location of  the file as a string no matter where it is, even if it gets moved to a different location? And if so how can it be done?

Comment: at a time how many .xml files you want to search and at a single location or from anywhere on the computer?

Comment: 1 xml file, anywhere in the computor

Comment: Not really - if the file is zipped, moved and unzipped you won't be able to track its movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean the file has been moved from the desktop to another directory, in which case have a look at the [`FileSystemWatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx).  If I understand your question correctly, this will allow you to track the file moving around.

Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: I'm not trying to find changes, just trying to get the string of a specific file in my computer. This xml file is on my desktop, but i want a code that if i put the xml file somewhere else on the computor it will still find it and give me a string saying where it is. Or maybe I'm not understanding 'FileSystemWatcher' class

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher enables you to track when a file has moved, which sounds like what you are trying to do - maybe you could give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an XML file in a certain directory, then, while the program is running the file moves to a completely different location, EX: from my desktop to My Computer, then the program notices this and replaces the string of where it used to be to a string of it's new location.

Comment: @SovietOnion that we be a move that FileSystemWatcher could detect.